# What is the correct way to say Women's Wear?

Tags: grammatical-number, apostrophe

In UK English what is the correct term for 'Women's Wear'?
For example, what should the department where all the women's clothes are be called?

Earlier I was 100% sure it would be "Women's Wear" but now after reading around a little I have seen numerous iterations.

Would a skirt be described as **woman's wear** and a department be termed **Women's Wear** as a skirt is singular belonging to a woman whereas the department contains numerous items intended for women?

Or, has the usage of 'womenswear' grown to the extent that it is now okay to use without people pointing out the error?

Also, I originally wrote this question with 'ware' not 'wear' but as it was suggested this was incorrect I edited it. I had previously checked that 'ware' was correct and was under the impression that 'ware' was a manufactured item (which would make sense to use) so please suggest if I should be using 'ware' rather than 'wear'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look for example at the floor plane from Harrods (http://issuu.com/harrodsonline/docs/storeguide_june?e=8294210/5711655, first floor), they denote it with

> Womenswear